# OpenLayers tile address

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

> server_url/map_folder//15/000/038/756/000/040/716

Can anyone explain how the above url matches a tile?

15 is ZOOM level but the rest is complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this question, a full explanation of the `OpenStreetMap` map tile URLs can be found on the [OpenStreetMap Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).